Azure Cli - automated login (non-interactive)
What is the best way to perform unattended az login in a "single-tenant/multiple-subscription" environment?
In this example. I'll use --device-code login method.

$ az login --use-device-code

To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code L96AYFHBU to authenticate.

Retrieving tenants and subscriptions for the selection...

[Tenant and subscription selection]

No     Subscription name    Subscription ID     Tenant
-----  -------------------  ------------------  --------------
[1] *  #sub-name-1#         #sub-id-1#          #tenant#
[2]    #sub-name-2#         #sub-id-2#          #tenant#

The default is marked with an *; the default tenant is '#tenant#' and subscription is '#sub-name-1#' (#sub-id-1#).

Select a subscription and tenant (Type a number or Enter for no changes): <enter>

Tenant: #tenant#
Subscription: #sub-name-1# (#sub-id-1#)

[Announcements]
With the new Azure CLI login experience, you can select the subscription you want to use more easily. Learn more about it and its configuration at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2271236

If you encounter any problem, please open an issue at https://aka.ms/azclibug

[Warning] The login output has been updated. Please be aware that it no longer displays the full list of available subscriptions by default.


To avoid confirm request, I tried az account set --subscription #sub-name-1# but this change only subscription default and confirmation prompt still remains.
I do not know is there is some azure config set available
Anyway, the only workaround I found is this one:

az login --use-device-code <<< "\n"



references:

Azure Cli how to change subscription default
az login should not select the default subscription (#27915)
Authenticate to Azure using Azure CLI
az login command



To avoid confirm request, I tried az account set --subscription #sub-name-1# but this change only subscription default and confirmation prompt still remains.

You can run the following command to disable confirmation prompts:
az config set core.disable_confirm_prompt=true

As an alternative, set the AZURE_CORE_DISABLE_CONFIRM_PROMPT environment variable or use a CLI configuration file.
For more details refer to CLI configuration values and environment variables.

I expected a comnand-line option in az login command, a -y option. Anyway, I missed the link to az config settings

I had a similar issue when running the Azure CLI az login command remotely.
It would automatically ask for a device login but then afterwards, it would still pause and ask which subscription I'd like to login with.
As I can't interact with it, it would just get stuck here with no way to proceed.
To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code MYCODE to authenticate.

Retrieving tenants and subscriptions for the selection...

[Tenant and subscription selection]

No     Subscription name           Subscription ID                       Tenant
-----  --------------------------  ------------------------------------  --------------
[1] *  Microsoft Partner Network   123*********************************  tenant
[2]    MSID_DEVX_RED_PPE           456*********************************  Microsoft
[3]    MSIT-DSR_DLP_Sentinel-PROD  789*********************************  Microsoft
[4]    StoreCore-PST-PIFD          011*********************************  Microsoft

The default is marked with an *; the default tenant is 'tenant' and subscription is 'Microsoft Partner Network' (123*********************************).

Select a subscription and tenant (Type a number or Enter for no changes): 

This prompt would appear even if I use az login --use-device-code which you might assume would force it to non-interactive.
To resolve this I used the linux yes command.
yes | az login

